# Trouble understanding Eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble understanding Eloquent relationships.

Say I have four tables with data

Users

```
id
...
```

UserCars

```
user_id
car_id
color_id
```

Cars

```
id
make
model
```

Colors

```
id
color
```

Now I understand how to get the UsersCars for a selected user with

```
User.php Model

public function cars()
{
    $this->hasMany(Car::class);
}
```

I can then get the User's car in to a view with

```
    public function show(User $user)
    {
        $cars= $user->cars;

        return $cars;
    }
```

So say a given user id 1 has 2 cars, I can get get his cars with $user->cars() which gives me something like in the view

```
{"id":1, "car_id":3, "color_id": 2}
{"id":1, "car_id":10, "color_id": 4}
```

But what I'm not getting is how to then further get the actual value of the relevant ids.  So once I've passed $users->cars() as $cars in my controller to my view I can then get the actual make and model and color of the users car.

Something like

```
@foreach ($cars as $car)
    {{ $car->make }} : {{ $car->model }}
    {{ $car->color }}
@endforeach
```

So once I call $user->cars() I need the something like

```
{"id":1, "car_id":3, "make" => "Ford", "model" => "Fiesta", "color_id": 2, "color":"red"}
{"id":1, "car_id":10, "make" => "Volkswagon", "model" => "Golf", "color_id": 4, "color":"blue"}
```

I hope that makes sense and any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all that data through relationships. Simply define them and load them as you need. First let's define every basic relationship in your model files

In Users model:

```
// User.php

public function user_cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\UserCar::class);
}
```

In UserCars model:

```
// UserCar.php

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}

public function car()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Car::class);
}

public function color()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(App\Color::class);
}
```

In Cars model:

```
// Car.php

public function user_cars()
{
    return $this->hasMany(App\UserCar::class);
}
```

With all that defined, you can access the relationships by just calling upon them. The difference between `$car->user_cars()` and `$car->user_car` is the returned object.

`$car->user_cars()` is an instance `HasMany` object and `$car->user_cars` is a `Collection` instance. It's basically the same as writing `$car->user_cars()->get()` so you want to go with the later most of the time.

Now let's see your controller method. Technically, you can return the `$user` and access all relationships in the view but every time you do, that's an additional query to the database. It's something you should avoid by getting all the data eager loaded first. Since you're using **Route Model Binding** to get the `$user`, you need to use the `load()` function. You can even load nested relationships, which is exactly what you're looking for.

```
public function show(User $user)
{
    // This tells eloquent to add the nested relationships to your User instance.
    $user->load('user_cars.car', 'user_cars.color');
    return $user;
}
```

Next, you can access them in the view just like you wanted

```
@foreach ($user->user_cars as $user_car)
    {{ $user_car->car->make }}
    {{ $user_car->car->model }}
    {{ $user_car->color->color }}
@endforeach
```

Read more on the subject https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand, appreciate it.  Also can this been further chained down deeper levels?

Comment: It can be chained as deep as you want. Performance might be an issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Your have incorrectly defined the relationship on the `User` to `Car`.

Since the relationship with users and cars are `many-to-many` you must use `belongsToMany()` eloquent relationship.

doc => https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

**User Model**

```php
public function cars()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Car::class, 'user_cars', 'user_id', 'car_id');
}
```

**Car Model**

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User:class, 'user_cars', 'car_id', 'user_id');
}
```

then you can access `cars` from the `user`, or `users` from the `car`.